# Creating a state diagram for a simple loop function

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, architecture, software-design, state-diagram

I have a simple function just returning the mirror image of the string passed. The code looks as follows:

```
function reverse(str){
        let reversed = "";    
        for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){        
            reversed += str[i];
        }    
        return reversed;
 }
```

The above system starts with an empty `reversed` value and goes on updating itself inside the loop. How would you enumerate the states in the above system? The states that I could figure out are `empty` --> `updated`.  This is it (Is this even correct?)

I am trying to understand the importance of state diagrams and how it could lead to finding out bugs with corner cases. So a state diagram with a simple system as above was something I wanted to start with.

Comment: Hi Amanda, Why not use start, in progress and Done?

Comment: Hi @TamirKlein We could. But I am not sure how would it explain the above system? Any ideas on how it could be represented?

Comment: Why are you saying "how would it explain the above system"? The code you provided has a starting point, processing and end which are represented by 3 state

Comment: @TamirKlein I think I failed to convey myself correctly. So 3 states, starting-point --> processing --> Done is all that is required to convey in a state diagram?

Comment: This is correct, If you have a more specific doubt please edit your question with as many details as possible.